# Multiprocessor support for `xz`?

Tags: xz

Is there a way to spread `xz` compression efforts across multiple CPU's?  I realize that this doesn't appear possible with `xz` itself, but are there other utilities that implement the same compression algorithm that would allow more efficient processor utilization?  I will be running this in scripts and utility apps on systems with 16+ processors and it would be useful to at least use 4-8 processors to potentially speed up compression rates.

Comment: https://github.com/vasi/pixz

Comment: Thanks, works fairly well. Not quite as efficient in terms of output size as xz itself and I was hoping it would output .xz compatible files, but this is not bad.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Multiprocessor (multithreading) compression support was added to `xz` in version 5.2, [in December 2014](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTg3MDM).

To enable the functionality, add the `-T` option, along with either the number of worker threads to spawn, or `-T0` to spawn as many CPU's as the OS reports:

```
xz -T0 big.tar
xz -T4 bigish.tar
```

The default single threaded operation is equivalent to `-T1`.

I have found that running it with a couple of hyper-threads less than the total number of hyperthreads on my CPU<sup>†</sup>  provides a good balance of responsiveness and compression speed.

<sup>† So `-T10` on my 6 core, 12 thread workstation.</sup>

As [scai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340631/scai) and [Dzenly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4053283/dzenly) said in comments

> If you want to use this in combination with `tar` just call `export XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 0"` before.
>
> or use smth like: `XZ_OPT="-2 -T0"`

Comment: If you want to use this in combination with `tar` just call `export XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 0"` before.

Comment: or use smth like: XZ_OPT="-2 -T0"

Comment: I used the option XZ -T4 but I just see only one processor being used.

Comment: Sorry @LucianoAndressMartini I don't know what to suggest. If you're using version 5.2 or later (check with `xz -V`) and `-T4` doesn't work on large files which aren't trivial to compress, I would suggest asking a question on [superuser.se] detailing your computer, operating system and kind of data you're compressing,

Comment: It seems that decompressing with multiple cores doesn't work, i.e. `xz --decompress -T0 file.tar.xz`. Is the decompression fundamentally non-parallelizable with xz?

Comment: Threading is all about speeding up compression @jmon12 , as decompression is trivial by comparison. From the man page "Threaded decompression hasn't been implemented  yet. It will only work on files that contain multiple blocks with size information in block headers. All files compressed in multi-threaded mode meet this  condition, but files compressed in single-threaded mode don't, even if `--block-size=size` is used."

Comment: So supposing I want tar to do multi thread xz compression I could do something like this:
tar cpO somename | xz -zT 5 -c > somename.tzx
or alternatively set the env variable XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 5" (or whatever number you think is most appropriate for your system .... 0 will probably allow you to do little else until you finish the compression)

Comment: @jmon12 pixz supports multi-threaded decompression